# hide system cursor in system wide

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, pyside, pywin32

I want to hide system cursor for 10s for some reason ,but I found

cursor.setShape(Qt.BlankCursor)

can only hide mouse cursor that is associated with QWidgets ,not in system wide ,i.e. when mouse cursor is hovering on QWidgets, it is invisible ,otherwise it is visible ,so is there any way to hide system cursor in system wide?

Comment: I am doing it on WinXP

Comment: I think this is the best that `QWindow` seems to allow.

Comment: I did some googling and the best I could find is the suggestion of changing the cursor to a transparent cursor using a win32 library. However, you would need to make/find the appropriate .cur file and hope that pywin32 actually gives you access to the appropriate windows functions. I also don't know how you would go about restoring the previous cursor. This is of course a pywin32 solution and not in any way related to Qt (assuming it works at all).

Answer (score 1):

The win32 system call [ShowCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works per-window only. You can access this from either ctypes or pywin32's [win32api](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__ShowCursor_meth.html). But apparently the cursor drawing is controlled by display driver and can only be affected by specific windows. You can't force another window to hide its cursor. Two options:

1. use ShowCursor(False) on your window, and for the display background, create a root window application that you spawn from your GUI app, it hides cursor; your app would cause it to exit after 10 seconds, but again if user moves mouse over other app windows they will see cursor.
2. make your application a root window application; then while in view, ShowCursor(False) will make cursor disappear everywhere on screen except system toolbar (which is a good thing).

I don't think it is a good idea anyways; what if your app crashes while the mouse is hidden? Then user can't use their desktop easily. Definitely good reason that this is not allowed.

Best approach is to think of a different solution to whatever problem led you to try cursor hiding.

Comment: have you tried it ? I fond win32api.ShowCursor(False) doesn't hide the cursor .